# Prime Spectrum Topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme, I want to show that there exists a unique scheme map $f:X\to \text{spec}(\mathbb{Z})$. Thus, far I have established that such a map, on the topology, is unique. Let $V$ be an affine open subset of $X$. Is it true that $V = f^{-1}(W)$ for some open set $W$ in $\mathbb{Z}$? Follow up question, if not true, does there exist a base for the topology of $X$ consisting of affine open sets which have this form? (Do not use anything other than the definitions, I am trying to prove a theorem from the ground up.)

Comment: There is a unique morphism of *schemes*, yes, but surely you can make more continuous maps? The topology on $\mathbb Z$ is not so delicate. Anyway, something like $\mathbb R[x]$ seems to be a counterexample.

Comment: You can do anything! But I think both of my points are still relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

For any $W\subset \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$, $f^{-1}(W)$ is a union of fibers. Of course not every affine open of $X$ will be a union of fibers. In particular, if $V$ is a union of fibers, you can usually consider a smaller piece which is not a union of fibers.

I would first suggest you play around with some simple examples. Start with say $X = \operatorname{Spec}(R[x])$ for some ring $R$ (first maybe let $R$ be a field, then more general rings...?). Can you come up with a morphism $\operatorname{Spec}(R[x])\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$? Can you come up with any others? Then perhaps consider some nonaffine scheme $X$. What's the simplest non-affine scheme people generally first learn about? Maybe projective space? Take the projective line, and try to come up with a morphism $\mathbb{P}^1_R\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$...etc. How does one even define a morphism from a non-affine scheme to an affine scheme? (Hint: First define it on affine pieces of the domain, then show they agree on intersections, and "glue").

After that, I would suggest you attempt to prove your thing as follows:

First consider the case where $X$ is affine, say $X = \operatorname{Spec}(R)$. Show that there exists a unique morphism $\operatorname{Spec}(R)\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$. In general, write $X$ as a union of affine schemes $\operatorname{Spec}(R_i)$, and show that the unique morphisms $f_i : \operatorname{Spec}(R_i)\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ agree on intersections, and thus glue to give a unique morphism $X\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$

Comment: My old idea is not working. Perhaps, I should pick an open set $U$ in $X$, cover $X$ by affine opens $V_i$, and consider $U\cap V_i$? Yes? Instead of trying to force each $V_i$ to be a pre-image of an open set in spec(Z).

Comment: I dunno why you'd consider $U\cap V_i$ instead of just the $V_i$'s. Also note that the intersection of two affine opens might not be affine. (It is affine if $X$ is separated, but otherwise it might not be, so you'll need to cover the intersection with distinguished affines - ie, open affines of the form D(f)).

Comment: Because the map is $\Gamma(W,O_\mathbb{Z}) \to \Gamma(f^{-1} W, O_X)$, by choosing $V$ for an open set in $X$ you do not have a map like that to construct the morphism.

Answer (score 0):

If $X=\mathbb A^1_\mathbb Z=\operatorname{Spec }\mathbb Z[T]$, the open affine subscheme $V=D(T)(=X\setminus V(T))$ is an affine open subset $U\subset X$ containing no fibre of the unique scheme morphism $\mathbb A^1_\mathbb Z \to\operatorname{Spec }\mathbb Z$.
Thus $V$ is  certainly not of the form $f^{-1}(W)$ for any $W\subset \operatorname{Spec }\mathbb Z$ .